# How to make an AJAX call to get some data and render the result server side? GET data on server -> render result -> send HTML to client

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, isomorphic-javascript

I am trying to figure out the best way to fetch data on the server side and render the resulting template there.

I've looked at some other articles on this -

One thing I saw was to use statics.  What does this mean?

Essentially, here's my very basic component code.  I know I have `componentDidMount` there, but I need to replace that somehow so that the request and result set is done server side but don't know how.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import * as actionCreators from '../../actions/fake-data';

class LandingPage extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getFakeData();
  }

  getFakeData() {
    this.props.actions.getFakeData();
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.props);
    return (
      <div>
        {
          this.props.fakeData.fetching ?
          <h2>Loading...</h2> :
          this.props.fakeData.response.map(item => <p>{item.title}</p>)
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}


function mapStateToProps(state) {
  console.log(state);
  return {
    fakeData: state.fakeData
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    actions: bindActionCreators(actionCreators, dispatch)
  };
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(LandingPage);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Too broad for StackOverflow. Generally (on the server) you have to fetch all data before rendering any components, populate your stores, and render your component tree with all stores populated. It's not easy and you don't get it for free. Here's some example code https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example/blob/master/src/server.js#L92 using this project https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-async-connect

Comment: That seems pretty difficult indeed!  But awesome, something new to try.  So quick question then if you have some time:  How do big sites that use react serve up the document with everything already rendered, even if its for location specific results (something like how Yelp does it)?

Comment: react-router works on the server. That's what the above boilerplate project uses and what I use for http://shaderfrog.com/app . A better place for these discussions is the #reactjs IRC room

Comment: Thanks a  lot man!  I'll check out the IRC.  Just one final question here and I'll close - when people say you can use statics, what do they mean?  Do you have an example of that?  All I saw was osmeone mention it, but no example.

Comment: hey check it out :D  https://github.com/ScaryWolfMan/react-ssr